# How to use a custom Formatter in JUL (java.util.logging) with Quarkus

Tags: quarkus

We have a custom JUL Formatter that mainly creates a JSON including properties for the MDC to ship it to ELK on our K8S cluster.
I haven't found a way to tell Quarkus to use a custom Formatter "com.example.CustomJulJsonFormatter" for all logging purposes. 
The application.properties file with all the log options does not include an option for the formatter (class). Or am I missing something here?

I successfully set the Formatter (through Handler) programmatically to the custom Formatter, but this misses at least the startup log messages and also it seems that this is discouraged:

```java
LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME).setUseParentHandlers(false);
Handler handler = new ConsoleHandler();
handler.setFormatter(new CustomJulJsonFormatter());
LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME).addHandler(handler);
```

Currently I am still very new with Quarkus, coming from payara micro where we ship a custom logging.properties in a docker container and set it up via "--logProperties", "/opt/payara/logging.properties" 
in ENTRYPOINT. Would be the easiest to do this as well here, but also I couldn't find a suitable jvm option to accomplish this with quarkus startup (especially the native version).

Let me know whether this makes any sense. Any help would be appreciated :)

edit: rough outline of the custom formatter class is

```java
...
import java.util.logging.Formatter;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;
import org.slf4j.MDC;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
...
public class CustomJulJsonFormatter extends Formatter {
    ...
    @Override
    public String format(LogRecord record) {
    // create JSON from LogRecord, MDC and Environment
    ...
    return jsonLog.toString();
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this has been resolved by the JSON logger now available with Quarkus. As of now (Quarkus v1.5.2), the extension `quarkus-logging-json` provide JSON-formatted logs similar to those that we used with our custom JUL formatter and everything works as expected.
MDC-handling is also not necessary anymore (didn't work very well in native anyway), as its main usecase in this context is covered by the use of `quarkus-smallrye-opentracing`.